# How to upload data to OpenSearch Dashboard

Tags: opensearch, opensearch-dashboards, opensearch-security-plugin

We have OpenSearch and OpenSearch Dashboard installed in Linux machine.
Now, we have a data set in excel or csv format, how to upload this data to create visualizations?

Please suggest if there any other way to upload or correct if this approach to upload data is incorrect

Thanks

Comment: Will it be one time operation?
What is your data size?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation, to start with -https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/opensearch/index-data/

Comment: Probably you need to create an index, then while creating a dashboard, you get an option to use the available indexes.